# New York Times API JSON

Tags: jquery, json, api

I’m creating a search engine using the New York Times API. How can I get a search term the user enters to be included in the JSON url?  Right now, what’s happening is that only the word “searchTerm” is being added, not the value of the text entered. Any ideas?  Please find below my code thus far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(nytapi) { 


$("#searchButton").click(function(search) {

    search.preventDefault()

    // Pick up search terms written in form 
    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val().trim(); 

    // Pick up number of results selected by user
    nResults = $("#recordsRetrieve").val(); 

    // Pick up start/end year
    startYear = $("#startYear").val().trim();

    endYear = $("#endYear").val().trim();

    var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

    url += '?' + $.param({
        'api-key': " ",
        'q': "searchTerm"

    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        method: 'GET',
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    // $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(result)); prints object onto page
    }).fail(function(err) {
        throw err; 
    });

    // Test to see if values are working 
    // $("#output").html(searchTerm);  
    // $("#output").html(nResults);
    // $("#output").html(endYear);  
    console.log(url); 


 });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `"searchTerm"` as parameter, change

```
url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key': "your api key",
    'q': "searchTerm"
});
```

To

```
url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key': "your api key",
    'q': searchTerm
});
```

Also, is advised to remove sensitive information from codes you post in public forums like this, please make sure to generate a new apikey.

Per @charlietfl comment, you can also pass the data parameter in your ajax call

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    q: searchTerm,
    'api-key': "[your key]"
  }
}).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

Comment: no need to use `$.param` manually for this , pass the object as `data` option and jQuery will do that internally